# Why does this Microsoft Unit Test Fail?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I have a unit test and I the number that gets stored in the actual variable from the Distance calcuation is 6.07328028312884, yet it is still saying the test is failing. Why?

```
        double expected = 6.07328028312884; 
        double actual;
        actual = target.Distance((double)latitude, (double)longitude);
        actual = actual / 1000;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Comment: Use this overload[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms243456%28v=VS.100%29.aspx] of Assert.AreEqual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Matt said, is not a good idea to compare for equality two floats, use `Math.Abs(expected-actual)<epsilon` with a small epsilon.

Answer (score 5):

floating point numbers are inaccurate by their very design. To test to that much accuracy is probably not going to work. What is the value of `actual`? you'll probably find it's off by expected just a tad, due to rounding and the general nature of floating point on computers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Microsoft UT's, but in CPPUNIT there is a special macro

CPPUNIT_ASSERT_DOUBLES_EQUAL(expected, actual)

which probably checks that the absolute value of the difference of expected and actual is less than some epsilon. There has to be an analogous function in Microsoft UTs